# Django system-wide install to virtualenv

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, gunicorn, pythonpath

I've recently deployed an application online using DigitalOcean single-click droplet setup which setup Django on Ubuntu with nginx and gunicorn. It came with a default django project which I've managed to change to my own. However, the default project doesn't use a virtualenv, it uses a system-wide install. So, the app only works if all the dependencies are installed on the system. I know this because if I uninstall django, it gives me an internal server error.

I would like to use the python in my virtualenv as the interpreter. And refer to the site-packages in that environment. I've tried fiddling with the PYTHONPATH and adding sys.path.append('/home/env/projectname') to the wsgi file but this doesn't work.

How can I achieve this?

**/etc/init/gunicorn.conf:**

```
setuid django
setgid django
chdir /home/env/projectname

exec gunicorn \
    --name=prj \
    --pythonpath=prj \
    --bind=127.0.0.1:9000 \
    --config /etc/gunicorn.d/gunicorn.py \
    prj.wsgi:application
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use the name "venv" for virtualenvs, because venv is a similar but different thing. "venv" and "virtualenv" are different ways to create isolated environments; venv is the new way, but it is only available for Python 3.3 and later, and so virtualenv is still more widely used.
2. To avoid confusion, remember that virtualenv (and venv, for that matter) is badly named. There is nothing virtual about it. It should better be called an isolated environment.

Now, gunicorn is a Python program. It **doesn't run** your Django project; it **imports** your Django project. So you can't possibly run gunicorn and your Django project in different environments, because they are actually one program. The way to run your Django project in a specific isolated environment is to start gunicorn in that isolated environment:

```
source your_virtualenv_dir/bin/activate    
exec gunicorn ...
```

For this to work, you must either have installed gunicorn in the virtualenv, or you must have installed gunicorn system-wide and created the virtualenv with `--system-site-packages`.

See also [this article of mine](http://djangodeployment.com/2016/11/01/virtualenv-demystified/).

Comment: I just deleted the venv and tried with this command. No luck unfortunately. I have edited my post and added /etc/init/gunicorn.conf. I have a feeling I'm doing something wrong there with the pythonpath bit. Sorry, I'm not very familiar with gunicorn

Comment: @zubhav I modified my answer after the new information you gave.

Comment: Thanks, I've finally fixed the issue by doing what you advised. I installed Gunicorn in my virtualenv and changed the 'exec gunicorn' command to refer to the virtualenv: 'exec /home/env/bin/gunicorn' and it works fine.

P.S Didn't realise venv and virtualenv were two different things. Was just using venv as slang haha. Now I know!

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the gunicorn into virtualenv and run it from there setting up the working directory and passing the wsgi:application.
[This tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04) may help you. [This tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-centos-7) may also be useful.