# Django app - What do I install in virtualenv vs system wide?

Tags: python, django, nginx

I'm working on creating my first "real" web app using Django.

Yesterday I learned I should be using a web server like Nginx to serve static files and pass off requests for dynamic content to my web app. I also learned that I need something like Gunicorn as the intermediary between the web server (Nginx) and my Django app.

My question is about virtualenv. It makes sense that we would contain app related software in it's own separate environment. What should I install in virtualenv, and what gets installed system wide? For example, in [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04) we seem to install Python, Nginx and the database system wide (because they're installed before virtualenv is installed) while Django and Gunicorn are installed in virtualenv. It makes sense that Gunicorn would have to go in the virtualenv since its importing our python app, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40821716/django-system-wide-install-to-virtualenv). Are the other things required to be installed system wide? Or can I pick either way? Is one way preferred over another?

Thanks!

Comment: http://thepythondjango.com/virtual-environment-python-pocket-guide/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtualenv is for managing Python libraries. It is not for managing Python itself, or for external services such as databases; it does however manage the Python libraries you use to access the database.

There's no room for confusion here, because there's simply no way to install Python itself or a database within a virtualenv.

Comment: This clears it up. Exactly the answer I was looking for. Thank you!